# Showing List of Acronyms without a result

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm trying to create a list of acronyms with Glossary.
My main .tex use a `\documentclass{Dissertate}`
Before trying using Glossary I had a .tex where manually added the acronym. To print on my document I used

```
\newcommand{\acrnyms}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista degli acronimi}
    \chapter*{Lista degli acronimi}
    \input{frontmatter/abbr.tex}
}
```

and then I printed it with

```
\acrnyms
```

Now, I would like to use my .tex file to print the list created by Glossary. I've added on my .cls file

```
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

after hyperref as indicated in the documentation of the package and I've added `\newacronym{3gpp}{3GPP}{3a Generazione Partnership Project}` after that
Once in my .tex file (the one that was used to manually write the acronymous) I've used the code `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` but it doesn't show anything

Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `\glsaddall` just before printing the acronyms?

Comment: It doesn't work. I think I'm doing something wrong with the printing the list of the acronyms because, when I go to use `\Gls{3gpp}` it works correctly and it prints the right acronym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had to copy

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
```

before `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` to print it